# Деление на абзацы

Tags: стилистика, оформление-текста, абзац

Насколько стилистически важно правильное деление текста на абзацы? Например, будет ли считаться большим недостатком раскрытие нескольких тем в одном абзаце или, наоборот, деление на несколько абзацев внутри, казалось бы, одной темы?

Answer (score 5):

Добрый день.
"Правильным" делением на абзацы принято считать авторское деление. Поэтому в младших классах при написании диктанта переход на новый абзац всегда проговаривается учителем, а в старших - проверяется. Неверное деление на абзацы засчитывается чаще всего как стилистическая ошибка.

Если текст Ваш, то Вы вправе делить его на части так, как Вам заблагорассудится, но от этого будет напрямую зависеть смысл. Длина текста также влияет на количество абзацев. Если у Вас по два-три предложения на похожие или чем-то связанные темы, а потом речь идёт совершенно о другом предмете, то их можно записать в один абзац.

*"Небо покрылось мохнатыми серыми тучами. Пошёл дождь.*

*Наталья закрыла книгу и отошла от окна."*

Если каждая из тем развивается, то их лучше разнести на разные абзацы.

*"Небо покрылось мохнатыми серыми тучами. Целый день они грозно висели над горизонтом, ежеминутно грозясь добраться и до этой забытой всеми деревней, и теперь, когда подул западный ветер, будто сердитые воины нерушимым строем двинулись завоёвывать чистое голубое пространство. Всё меньше и меньше оставалось проблесков в их мрачной, бурлящей массе. Пару раз мелькнули молнии и раздался первый громовой раскат.*

*Пошёл дождь. Сперва отдельные крупные капли тяжело ударились о песчаную поверхность деревенской дороги, а через пять минут уже не осталось ни единого сухого места и тогда-то грянул настоящий ливень. Косые струи заливали раскрытые окна, наполняли ямы водой, стегали по бокам мычащих коров, к которым спешили мгновенно вымокшие до нитки хозяева..."*

Если соединить эти два абзаца в один, текст будет неудобно читать. Но если, например, Наталья с её книгой окажется не так важна повествователю, он может приписать предложение, посвящённое ей к предыдущей теме:

*"...вымокшие до нитки хозяева. Наталья поспешно закрыла книгу и отошла от окна.*

*Из комнаты выбежала напуганная грозой собака."*

Ещё можно "подвязывать" новый абзац к прошлому. То есть, в одном указать предмет, который будет действовать в следующем:

*"...вымокшие до нитки хозяева. Наталья поспешно закрыла книгу и отошла от окна.*

*Оно пугало её: не так давно Антон выбил крепление и теперь старые створки в любой момент могли распахнуться и впустить в уютный дом бушующую стихию. Кроме того, девушка всё ещё боялась молний и хрупкое стекло не казалось ей надёжной защитой от них."*

В общем, всё зависит от длины абзаца. Считается правильным, когда все части текста примерно одинаковы. Конечно, бывают более длинные и более короткие, но если в одном абзаце у В 500 слов, а в другом 50, то надо что-то менять) В чужом тексте предпочтительно соблюдать авторское абзацное деление, хотя оно иногда бывает и нелогичным)

Comment: Спасибо. Но как понять "будет напрямую зависеть смысл"? Это значит, что абзац выделяет высказанную в нём мысль?

Comment: @IgorGovorushko, да, я наверное коряво выразилась. Абзацы именно что подчёркивают ту мысль, которую автор считает основной. Значит в некоторых случаях из-за неправильного членения по абзацам можно потерять или кардинально изменить смысл всего текста. Например, что-то вроде такого в начале книги:


"Матрос достал заветную табакерку. Он шёл по улице навстречу закуривающему."

Иногда автор вводит нового персонажа с помощью местоимения, не сразу выдавая его имя. Эти два предложения о разных людях и должны быть разными абзацами. Если слить их в один, смысл теряется: к кому это там идёт матрос?

Comment: Или вот в системе комментирования абзацы не предусмотрены. Здесь правда и не напишешь много, но даже в коротких текстах абзацы часто бывают необходимы. Если в двух словах, то у них два важных назначения: удобное деление текста, сохраняющее читателям остатки зрения, и структурное деление мысли для удобства понимания.

Comment: Александра, извините, пожалуйста, но "заблагорассудится" пишется без мягкого знака.

Comment: @user183861, да, конечно. Опечаталась.

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я знаю, лучше поделить одну, казалось бы, тему на несколько абзацев. Вы как автор всегда сможете объяснить, что началась новая микротема. А вот наоборот будет сделать сложнее. Вас могут обвинить в неумении структурировать мысли и мыслить логически.
Поэтому лучше сделать больше абзацев, и пусть это деление будет хотя бы мало-мальски обосновано.